# Conversion Failed when Converting DateTime

Tags: t-sql, casting

This is my first post so any mistakes apologies in advance.

I am trying to convert a character string into a date format. My string is in the format '20110709_000000'.

I have tried the following queries after research but both return me the following error:
'Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.'

I have tried

```
Select CAST(REPLACE('20110709_000000','_', '') AS DATETIME)
```

and

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE('20110709_000000','_', ''),109).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `000000` is `hhmiss` you can use [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to get the parts and build a string on the format `yyyymmdd hhmiss` that you can cast to `datetime`.

```
declare @ds varchar(15) = '20110709_102030'

select cast(substring(@ds,  1, 8)+' '+
            substring(@ds, 10, 2)+':'+       
            substring(@ds, 12, 2)+':'+
            substring(@ds, 14, 2) as datetime)
```

Result:

```
-----------------------
2011-07-09 10:20:30.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the 000000 at the end?  This should work:

```
Select CAST(REPLACE('20110709_000000','_000000', '') AS DATETIME)
```